# How to create a specific form of table?

Tags: tables

I'm unable to create this table on latex
[image]

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: What is special in this table? Numbers in the first column?  Just make table with `classic` numbers and then search for fonts, which has numbers in circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities for your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mdwtab,booktabs}
    \usepackage{pifont}

    \begin{document}
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
    \hline
No  &   Name    &   sex \\  \hline
1   &   Euler   &   M   \\  \hline
2   &   Noether &   F   \\  \hline
3   &   Gauss   &   M   \\  \hline
    \end{tabular}
\quad
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
    \hline
No  &   Name    &   sex \\  \hline
\ding{192}      &   Euler   &   M   \\  \hline
\ding{193}      &   Noether &   F   \\  \hline
\ding{194}      &   Gauss   &   M   \\  \hline
    \end{tabular}
\quad
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
    \hlx{hv}
No  &   Name    &   sex \\  \hlx{hv}
\ding{192}      &   Euler   &   M   \\  \hlx{vhv}
\ding{193}      &   Noether &   F   \\  \hlx{vhv}
\ding{194}      &   Gauss   &   M   \\  \hlx{vh}
    \end{tabular}
\quad
    \begin{tabular}{clc}
    \toprule
No  &   Name    &   sex \\  \midrule
1   &   Euler   &   M   \\  
2   &   Noether &   F   \\  
3   &   Gauss   &   M   \\  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

For `No` search in document `symbols-a4.pdf`, probably is somewhere in it.